# User's id shared between activity in login system

Tags: android, mysql, database, authentication

I think about login system for my android app. I have never make login system for app, I made login only for PHP on web so I am not sure how it is work in android app.

**So the problem is how share id of user between activites.**

I will have first activity with login, then second with menu (there will be user after successful login). When user click on button in menu the list of his categories (for every user different) will be shown. So I need get id user from my mysql database in login activity, share it to my category activity and there send like a Json to get categories for unique user.

The id of user will be primary and foreign key in my database (**one table with users** and **one with all categories for all users**)

How is normally make this thing? I thought about put.extra in Intent but maybe is more better way how to do it.

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: I try nothing in this app (normally I used Intent in other app). I only want know what is a standard way how share user id in this type of app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple ways to achieve that :

**Method 1:**
Use static class setter and getter method:

create static class and set values from first activity and get value from second activity

**Method 2:**

Post your values through the intent

**Method 3:**

Use database to store data from one activity and get data from other activity

**Method 4:**

Use Shared preference

Comment: Thx, this is what I want - ways how share user id. There are some big advantages and disadvatanges of using concrete way? For example using Intent (it looks like a easiest way for me - like beginner)

Comment: Then you can use method 2 right. Passing value as putExtras and get value using getExtras

Comment: One of the disadvantage using intent is if you have 3 activities(A, B, C) and you want values in C then you must pass value from A to B and B to C. In this case better you choose other methods.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I wil try learn shared preferences from tutorial which Shadik posted.

Comment: @Bulva don't forget that SharedPreferences is just a simple XML file in the system. Do never add any sensitive information there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Webservice for sign in on Login Activiyt. When user Sign in successfully then return success message with id/userid(As per your Need).

After getting the id/userid from webservice when user loged in successfully then at same activity use SharedPrefrence Or Setter Getter for storing the userid and then move on to second Activity.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

At the starting of second activity get the userid from sharedPrefrence Or Setter Getter method as you stored previously and implement the condition as per your requirment.

Comment: Thank you for that tutorial, I don't know what exactly find on internet (so i can't find answer). I will try this way too. :-)